# Generating customers according to schedule in simpy

Tags: python, simulation, simpy

I am trying to simulate customer arrivals at specific times (not generated according to statistical distribution) using Simpy v3. The arrival times are defined in the csv file that I loaded into pandas dataframe.

In the previous version of Simpy (v2.2), there was an argument for the activate function "at" which would activate a customer at a particular instance
`activate(c,c.visit(timeInBank),at=5.0)`.
How to do this in Simpy version 3??

The dataframe 'df' passes the arrival times for each customer

```
df.head()

arrival_time  start_service  end_service  waiting_time  service_duration
09:00:20      09:01:00       09:06:00     0.40      5.00
09:01:00      09:02:20       09:04:00     1.20      1.40
```

.

```
import random
import simpy
import pandas as pd `

def source(env, df, counter):
    for i, row in df.iterrows():
        c = client(env, 'Client%02d' % i, counter, row,time_in_bank=row["service_duration"])
        env.process(c)   

def client(env, name, counter, row, time_in_bank):
    arrive = env.now # probably some changes to be done here
    print('%s arrived at %7.4f' % (name,arrive))

    with counter.request() as req:
        results = yield req

        wait = env.now - row["waiting_time"]

        print('%s waited %6.3f' % (name, wait))

        yield env.timeout(time_in_bank)
        print('%s exited the office at %7.4f' % (name, env.now))


df = pd.read_csv("arrivals.csv",sep=",",header=0)

env = simpy.Environment()

counter = simpy.Resource(env, capacity=1)
env.process(source(env, df.head(), counter))
env.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a [start_delayed](https://simpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_reference/simpy.util.html) function in simpy.util that might fit what you need.

```
import random
import simpy
from simpy.util import start_delayed
import pandas as pd

def source(env, df, counter):
    for i, row in df.iterrows():
        c = client(env, 'Client%02d' % i, counter, row,time_in_bank=row["service_duration"])
        # Some code to format timestamp to seconds
        delay = timestamp_to_seconds(row["arrival_time"])
        start_delayed(env, c, delay)   

def client(env, name, counter, row, time_in_bank):
    arrive = env.now # probably some changes to be done here
    print('%s arrived at %7.4f' % (name,arrive))

    with counter.request() as req:
        results = yield req

        wait = env.now - row["waiting_time"]

        print('%s waited %6.3f' % (name, wait))

        yield env.timeout(time_in_bank)
        print('%s exited the office at %7.4f' % (name, env.now))


df = pd.read_csv("arrivals.csv",sep=",",header=0)

env = simpy.Environment()

counter = simpy.Resource(env, capacity=1)
env.process(source(env, df.head(), counter))
env.run()
```